# Change the scoring function for array using best score for elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, elasticsearch

Consider I have a text field called 'question' with element
`['one','one shift','one apple']`.
Now say the query is `'one'` with the following search query:

```
query": {
    "match": {
        "question": {
            "query": 'one',
        }
    }
}
```

I want the scoring function to use the best score among the three matches `'one'`, `'one shift'`, `'one apple'` for the text field. How should I modify that? I am aware there is a [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), but I am not sure how to achieve that.